# Finding all columns with names containing "gender" in a list of dataframes in r and subset them?

Tags: r, list, select, nested, subset

I have a nested list, which is basically a list with a bunch of dataframes inside. Some of those dataframes have the column "gender" and I want to extract all of those columns and basically rbind them together so I have a long vector or dataframe with gender (and a race column too), and potentially some other variables down the road. I wish using select and contains and stuff in the tidyverse would work, but I don't think I can make it do so.

Here's some simulated data and the scenario (though in reality I have multiple lists with thousands of dfs with lots of variables):

```
df1 <- data.frame("name" = c("John","mia"), "race" = c("asian","black"), "gender" = c("male","female"))
df2 <- data.frame("name" = c("nick","kate"), "race" = c("asian","white"), "gender" = c("male","female"))
df3 <- data.frame("name" = c("ed","may"), "race" = c("black","white"), "gender" = c("male","female"))
df4 <- data.frame("name" = c("Jo","mary"), "race" = c("white","black"), "gender" = c("male","female"))

lista <- c(df1, df2)
listb <- c(df3, df4)
```

I want something like:

```
newdf <- data.frame("race" = c("asian", "black", "asian", "white", "black","white", "white","black"), "gender" = c("male","female", "male","female", "male","female", "male","female")
```

What I wish is that I could do something like:

```
list %>% select(df) %>% select(contains("race"), contains("gender") %>% 
         bind_rows(.)
```

But obviously that isn't something I can do in that way.

Comment: Please do add sample of input and expected output in your post too.

Comment: I added some sample data and the idea of what I'm trying to do :)

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist <- list(length=3)
mylist[[1]] <- data.frame(gender = c("male", "female"), num=1:2, stringsAsFactors = F)
mylist[[2]] <- data.frame(gender = c("female", "male"), var=3:4, stringsAsFactors = F)
mylist[[3]] <- data.frame(something=letters[1:5], stringsAsFactors = F)


unlist(lapply(mylist, function(x) x$gender))
```

Comment: Thanks-- I know I can do this pretty easily on the individual lists, but I have a lot of them and I'm trying to automate it :)

Comment: I'm confused: do you have a lot of data.frames stored in a list (in which case my solution will work) or do you have a lot of lists?

Answer (score 0):

It would be great to have an example of your data, but here's start:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map_dfr(lst_of_dataframes, ~select(.x, contains('gender')))
```

for the case you posed, the geniuses creating the `tidyverse` have you covered:

```
map_dfr(lst_of_dataframes, ~select(.x, matches('gender|race')))
```

Comment: This is awesome!! Thank you! If I wanted to subset those dataframes in the list, do you know how I might do that, with say race and gender? I know `map()` will give me a list of lists back, but I can't do something like `map(lst_of_dataframes, ~select(.x, contains('gender' | 'race')))`. Maybe I can use stringr or something.

Comment: the `matches` selector should cover that, updated post

Comment: Actually, I think I got it! `map(lst_of_dataframes, ~select(.x, contains("gender''), contains("race"))`. Though, if you have anything more efficient in mind, I'd be happy to hear :)